# If a path satisfies Euler-Lagrange, does that necessarily mean that it has to minimize the action?

Tags: physics, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I asked a question recently on here and got very insightful answers. Now that I understand the proof of the variational method to obtain the EL equation, I have a new question.

The proof that I went through started with the supposition that there is a special path $y(t)$ which minimized the action integral $S$. We then proceeded to create a family of paths which $y(t)$ belongs to, and this family is parametrized by $\alpha$. From design we know that the path which minimizes the action integral must occur at $\alpha = 0$ from the initial supposition. After some integral manipulation, we get the EL equation (which is satisfied by the special path $y(t)$).

My question is this. If we were to go backwards and find some path that satisfies EL, does that have to imply that it gives the minimum of the action?

Comment: Not necessarily. It can be a minimum, a maximum, or a saddle-point.

Comment: For a simple counterexample, take any functional with a minimum then negate it. It will have the same EL equation but will now have a maximum instead.